# Get child/parent relations of polygons

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to extract parent/child relations from the Open Street Map database using `ST_Contains(parent, child)`, however I am exceptionally bad at SQL.

In a nutshell, the table `planet_osm_polygon` looks like this:

```
| osm_id | name      | admin_level | way            |
-------------------------------------------------
| 4667   | France    | 2           | {polygon data} |
| 4667   | Normandie | 4           | {polygon data} |
| 4667   | A place   | 6           | {polygon data} |
etc...
```

I would like to extract the parent/child relations where a child is a row in which the polygon is within its parent and where the admin_level is as low as possible, but not equal to that of its parent (might seem obvious, just sayin).

**What I have done so far**

I have manage to write a query that gives me a parent of each area, but not one with the lowest one possible admin_level - so an area with admin_level=6 can appear with a parent that has admin_level=2. I want the child to appear together with a parent that has the lowest admin_level possible, which would be 4 in that case.

This is my failing query:

```
SELECT
DISTINCT ON (childTable.osm_id)
childTable.admin_level AS child_level,
childTable.name AS child_name,
parentTable.name AS parent,
parentTable.admin_level AS parent_level

FROM planet_osm_polygon AS childTable
RIGHT JOIN planet_osm_polygon AS parentTable
ON ST_Contains(parentTable.way, childTable.way)
AND childTable.admin_level > parentTable.admin_level;
```

And here is an example result of the fail:

```
| Child level | Child name | Parent name | Parent level |
---------------------------------------------------------
| 6           | Some place | France      | 2            |
| 4           | Another    | France      | 2            |
| 6           | And again  | France      | 2            |
etc...
```

Here is how I would like it to be:

```
| Child level | Child name | Parent name | Parent level |
---------------------------------------------------------
| 6           | Some place | A region    | 4            |
| 4           | A region   | France      | 2            |
etc...
```

*Note: I have removed all data related to admin_level 1, 3, 5, so I only have polygons with admin_level 2, 4 and 6, However this might differ for other contries so you I don't think it's possible to hardcode the admin_levels*

Answer (score 2):

If I get your question right you can use the `row_number()` window function to assign each of the parents of a child a number which is `1` for the one with the lowest admin level and filter on that.

```
SELECT child_level,
       child_name,
       parent_name,
       parent_level
       FROM (SELECT childtable.admin_level child_level,
                    childtable.name child_name,
                    parenttable.name parent_name,
                    parenttable.admin_level parent_level
                    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY childtable.name
                                       ORDER BY parenttable.admin_level) rn
                    FROM planet_osm_polygon childtable
                         RIGHT JOIN planet_osm_polygon parenttable
                                    ON st_contains(parenttable.way, childtable.way)
                                       AND childtable.admin_level > parenttable.admin_level) x
       WHERE rn = 1;
```

If you have an unique ID `<id>` for each polygon you should replace `PARTITION BY childtable.name` with `PARTITION BY childtable.<id>` or check that the names are unique. You might get false results with different places sharing a name otherwise.

I'm also not sure if your right join shouldn't be some other join. If you want to show all parents, even if no child for them exists, keep the right join. If you want to show all children, orphans too, make it a left join. If you want to only show children that have parents and parents that have children use an inner join.

Comment: Thank you so much for this, I will try it right away!

Comment: I ran this and it didnt quite produce the results I was expecting, but it has pointed me towards the right direction. I will get back with more info